# how can I store data to a jsonfile in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have an httpservice in a controller which returns json. How could I save this result to a file on disk? I would like to use the result as a mock file so I don't have to be online to use the service.

Comment: you can create a seperate json file, and call that file using $http.get() method

Comment: yes I know. I am trying to figure out how to save the json when I call the actual working service when I am online. So when I am not online I can still have some data in the json file

Comment: We would like to clear more detail of your question.
Even if you could use json data somehow in offline, how do you imagine to use it without html and javascript including angularjs?
By any chance, your context of the question is **not** web application? For example chrome apps or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just mocking the data you can just copy and paste the result of the webservice and expose it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .value('myMockData', {
    "foo": "bar"
});
```

If you're switching the app from online/offline you can use local storage to store the result from the webservice.